Is there a one-liner command or tool to create a virtual input device from default output on pipewire?
I'm looking for a way (better if run from command line or that can be a permanent setting) that creates a virtual input device (that shows as a virtual mic or similar) when/while run.
The main goal is to be able to record the default output with arecord or pw-record without ambient noise, but this should be easy to turn-on and turn-off and not requiring the installation of graphical tools.
I've seen various gui-based tools (requiring visual configuration, connecting boxes, etc.) and also complex tutorials on connecting outputs and inputs using pipewire, but I'm really looking for something simple.  Something that allows me to select this virtual device as a microphone only when I'm trying to record the output, and then I can select the actual mics again when finished.

Here is a clean and simple way to start and stop the virtual microphone for recording system audio.
#!/bin/bash

# Start a PipeWire loopback to create a virtual microphone
pw-loopback &
LOOPBACK_PID=$!

# Instructions to the user
echo "Virtual microphone created. Recording system audio via this virtual mic."
echo "Press any key to stop the virtual microphone..."

# Wait for user input to terminate the virtual microphone
read -n 1

# Stop the PipeWire loopback
kill $LOOPBACK_PID
echo "Virtual microphone stopped."


pw-loopback & starts the loopback in the background.
LOOPBACK_PID=$! captures the process ID of the loopback.
The script waits for the user to press any key before killing the loopback process with kill $LOOPBACK_PID.


I'm getting the error pw-loopback: unrecognized option '--playback-default'

I have changed it. It works fine on my computer, it's 5 in the morning over here and the output woke up the neighbors :-)
